# cakePHP - form value coudn't validate

Tags: php, cakephp

My controller:

```
class PostsController extends AppController 
{
    function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }
    function add(){
        if(!empty($this->data))
        {
            $this->Post->save($this->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash('the post was saved successfully');
            $this->redirect('/posts/index');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('the post was not saved');
        }
    }
}
```

My model

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $validate = array(
        'title'=>array(
            'title_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'$this post is missing a title'
            ),
            'title_must_be_unique'=>array(
                'rule'=>'isUnique',
                'message'=>'A post with this title already exists'
            )
        ),
        'body'=>array(
            'body_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'this post is missing the body'
            )

        )   
    );
}
```

And my view (I don't use cake html and form helper)

```
<form action="<?= $this->base.'/posts/add' ?>" method="post">
    <label>title</label>
    <input type="text" name="data[Post][title]" /><br />
    <label>body</label>
    <textarea type="text" name="data[Post][body]"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Problem:

when I deliberately left out the fields, the form submitted value to database anyway.

And I'm trying to avoid using html-helpers.

Comment: I'm going to comment here because hopefully your "answer/rant" will be deleted.  Cake is as flexible as it needs to be.  You want to not use the framework's built in mechanisms.  You're freely allowed to do that.  Whip up your own code to replace the FormHelper and use that.  But, you can't expect to say "I'm not gonna use the framework's tools but I want the framework to perform as if I did."  That's completely unreasonable.

Comment: I agree with @Charles; it's like replacing OS X with Windows and then complaining that your Mac doesn't do the things Apple advertises.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the data was saved? Because the controller will redirect you away from the page even if the data doesn't validate.

```
function add(){
    if(!empty($this->data) ) {
        if( $this->Post->save($this->data) )
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('the post was saved successfully');
            $this->redirect('/posts/index');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('the post was not saved');
        }
    }
}
```

The next problem is that the validation messages won't show in the view. You need the helpers there to create them, it's a lot of work to do that manually. May I ask why you're not using them?

Comment: I'm sure the data was saved, I've checked. that means validation is doing it's job.

Comment: I'm not using form helpers because I prefer html code in the view, a convention I've been used to when I worked with other framework.

Comment: Your data might be saving but your validation messages won't appear unless you do a lot of manual work to hack around not using the Form helper.  I can understand your desire to do this, but I would definitely use at least the Form helper for stuff like this, it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Plus you can freely ignore every other method in the helper, you just need to use the `$this->Form->error()` after the fields. Your choice, of course, but the helpers actually are very helpful.

Comment: `$this->Form->error()` is nice but I also want to point out that the Form helper will also pre-populate data in your Forms.  For example if the post title isn't formatted properly and gets rejected you'd likely lose whatever is in your body element as well.  The Form helper would retain on to this info for you.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be off-topic, but if you're using pure html just because you don't need extra html generated by Form helper (like fieldsets, input wrapped with div, auto-generated label), then you can always use form helper element options
e.g.

`<label>title</label> <?php echo $this->Form->input('title', 
array('label'=>false, 'div'=>false, 'legend'=>false)
);?>`

However I totally agree with @Charles and @Juhana : true power of framework can be unleashed when following it's conventions. So if you want Cake works as advertised - implement as docs advise.